# Titan graph leaf nodes

Tags: java, gremlin, titan

I've a graph like "  A-->B-->C  "  now i removed vertex "B". Now my graph contains vertices A and C and no edges, here C is the leaf node it doesn't linked with any other nodes.
          Now my doubt is
           what is advantage of leaf nodes when they doesn't contain relation ship with any other nodes.(It is memory wastage right..?)

Comment: Graph is only an imagined structure. It is only useful when you associate with something real. So whether "C" is useful depends on your usage.

Comment: No 'C' is not useful in my graph

Comment: See if my graph contain 1000's leaf nodes like 'C'. What about my memory usage?

Comment: If your code works if you remove `C`s, you can remove them.

Comment: For small number of vertices it is ok we can remove but if my graph contain 1000's or lack leaf nodes it is very difficult to delete all vertices right??

Comment: Is it titan providing any method to delete these type of leaf nodes?

Comment: I only know a little about graphs. I don't know anything about titan.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether you plan to link back up with C node.  If C cannot ever possibly be used again in your use case, then yes, C is a waste of resources.

It depends on your Graph's purpose.